# Copy and Paste range contents X times through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I need to create lists of data that duplicate values X number of times. Example: I have store #, City, State, and Zip that I need to copy/paste to duplicate it 10 times. This would create 10 rows of the same Store #, City, State, and Zip in the exact same column order - just repeating the rows as many times as I need.

I've tried numerous other macros, but they never cover multiple columns of data and are limited in range. I need this macro to at least cover ~2,000 rows of data.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

There are two options: copy range or set values.

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim sCnt As String
    Dim rSrc As Range
    ' Get source range
    Set rSrc = Range("A3:D3")
    sCnt = InputBox("How many times do you to copy data?")
    If Len(sCnt) > 0 And VBA.IsNumeric(sCnt) Then
        ' Copy to destination range which starts at F3
        rSrc.Copy Range("F3").Resize(CInt(sCnt), rSrc.Columns.Count)
        ' If cell format is NOT needed, set values is more efficient
        'Range("F3").Resize(CInt(sCnt), rSrc.Columns.Count).Value = rSrc.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Repeated Rows

[image]

```vb
Sub CopyRepeatedRows()
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Copy Repeated Rows"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SRC_SHEET As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_FIRST_ROW As String = "A3:D3"
    Const DST_SHEET As String = "Sheet1"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "F3"
    Const MIN_REPEATS As Long = 1
    Const MAX_REPEATS As Long = 50
    Const QUESTION As String = "How many times do you want the rows repeated?"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Get the number of repeats.

    Dim iString As String: iString = InputBox(QUESTION, PROC_TITLE, MIN_REPEATS)
    
    Dim iNumber As Long
    
    If Len(iString) > 0 Then
        If IsNumeric(iString) Then
            iNumber = CLng(iString)
        End If
    End If
    
    If iNumber < MIN_REPEATS Or iNumber > MAX_REPEATS Then
        MsgBox "Use a number between " & MIN_REPEATS & " and " _
            & MAX_REPEATS & ".", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Reference the source range.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET)
    
    Dim srg As Range, srCount As Long, cCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range(SRC_FIRST_ROW)
        Set srg = .Resize(sws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
        Dim lCell As Range:
        Set lCell = srg.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No data found in range """ & srg.Address _
                & """ of worksheet """ & sws.Name & """!", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        srCount = lCell.Row - .Row + 1
        cCount = .Columns.Count
        Set srg = .Resize(srCount)
    End With
    
    ' Write the values from the source range to the source array.
    
    Dim sData():
    
    If srCount * cCount = 1 Then
        ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = srg.Value
    Else
        sData = srg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Define the destination array.
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = srCount * iNumber
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    ' Write the values repeated from the source array to the destination array.
    
    Dim sr As Long, i As Long, dr As Long, c As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        For i = 1 To iNumber
            dr = dr + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                dData(dr, c) = sData(sr, c)
            Next c
        Next i
    Next sr
                
    ' Reference the destination range.
                
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL).Resize(dr, cCount)
    
    ' Write the values from the destination array to the destination range
    ' and clear below.
    
    drg.Value = dData
    drg.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - drg.Row - dr + 1).Offset(dr).Clear
    
    ' Inform.
    
    Dim Times As String:
    
    Select Case iNumber
        Case 1: Times = "once"
        Case 2: Times = "twice"
        Case Else: Times = iNumber & " times"
    End Select
        
    MsgBox "Copied rows repeated " & Times & ".", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```